# How to complete a number in Access?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, database-design

I am coding an Access Database as a workshop project. I am using a form to introduce data in a table but I have a little problem. I have two fields named Customer Number and Invoice Number. Their structure are like this:

Customer Number: 430123456 (430+customer number)
Invoice Number: 161234567 (last 2 digits of the year + invoice number)

I'd like the user to enter only the variable part of the numbers (customer and invoice number) and let access fill the constant part (430 or year) while keeping the length of the field constant (9 digits in both cases). How can I do it?

Cheers!

Dani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I've just gone to the format property of the field and add the following:

```
"430."000\.000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build them like this:

```
CustomerNumber = Val("430" & Right(Format(UserInputNumber, "000000"), 6))
InvoiceNumber = Val(Format("yy", Date) & Right(Format(UserInputNumber, "0000000"), 7))
```

or as *ControlSource* for two textboxes:

```
=Val("430" & Right(Format([UserInputNumber],"000000"),6))
=Val(Format("yy",Date()) & Right(Format([UserInputNumber],"0000000"),7))
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier, I've been away. A basic question, where do I build the number? I guess it is in the table in edit, mode, what else? I've tried to put it in the format section but I only get ###. Thanks.

Comment: I've partially solved it, but I still have some problems with the invoice number (last 2 digits of the year + invoice number). Where should I place your code?

Comment: That would be somewhere in your code - or you can modify to use as _ControlSource_ for two textboxes displaying the numbers. See edit.